# Exporting SSRS Report to the same excel workbook every month

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel

I am new to SSRS and I'm trying to automate a report for our client.  I have comnpleted the design but I have not deployed it to the reporting server.  When I manually export the report to excel via the design viewer in Business Intelligence Studio 2008, I get a new workbook every time.  However, I want this report to export to excel automatically, to the same workbook, on the same worksheet, every time it is run per month. This way, i can create an excel workbook that contains the report data and other worksheets with templates that auto populate, based on the report data.

I'd like to avoid exporting it to a new workbook, then copying and pasting into the workbook with all my templates manually. I'd also like to avoid exporting to CSV or XML and then importing it into Excel.

Is this possible? Perhaps this is via the deployment of the report and I just haven't gotten that far?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi welcome to stack overflow.

Can l suggest looking at another related technology SSIS (Sql Server Integrated Services).  This will allow you to extract the data from a data source.  Then using the the out of the box components export the data to Excel.  Once you have created the package in SSIS, the package can then be scheduled to run (if you have SQL server instance) to run at specific times.  I have used that solution in my current role to produce reports automatically and then email then to various people.

The link below shows one method of exporting to excel using BIDS, and suggests some other ways.

http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/ssis-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-excel/

Also this link http://dougbert.com/blog/post/Excel-in-Integration-Services-Part-1-of-3-Connections-and-Components.aspx  is one of three that covers the topic of connecting SSIS to Excel, has some excellent advice IMHO

SSRS has a scheduler build in, which can run reports at specified times, this l think is only available in the enterprise edition.  This facility will if memory serves right, will not insert the data, only create or overwrite the file each time.   So l am not sure if this is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think the issue with using SSIS to export to excel is that SSIS won't retain the formatting that I want.  It will just be a dump of the data to excel. Then I have to use excel formulas to populate the values in the formatting I want.

Comment: Good point, but nonetheless I think @BobF's answer about sums up your options. Note that the last paragraph may contain the best option for you.

Comment: Hi Chrissy Swor just seen you comment regarding formatting.  Yes l agree :-) exactly what we found *sigh*  The only solution that we could find that suits our situation, was to create some VBA which formats the data, when the workbook opens.  The solution is for a finance company hence formatting must be spot on.  Not a great solution, however it works for us, and our users, and fits within narrow parameters we have to work in.

Comment: Thanks Bob. That is what I ended up doing to.